# Adding a thin vertical image above the scroll view

Tags: android, view, scroll

I have a vertical scroll view which has different images scrolling horizontally. Now , what I want to do is add a badge or strip above the scroll view. Just like a wrapping strap above the scroll view and it is going to be an image.

Here is the xml file if it helps:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border1">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="250px" android:fillViewport="false">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinMid"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20px" android:layout_marginBottom="20px">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_list_one"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="800dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_arrow_left"
                android:layout_weight="0.17">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70px" android:layout_marginLeft="60px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_keo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="50dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_blahblah" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="35dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_btl2" android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_list_one"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="800dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_arrow_left"
                android:layout_weight="0.17">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70px" android:layout_marginLeft="60px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_adlerbock" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="50dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_blahblah" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="35dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_btl1" android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_list_one"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="800dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_arrow_left"
                android:layout_weight="0.17">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70px" android:layout_marginLeft="60px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_moosehead" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="50dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_blahblah" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="35dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_btl2" android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_list_one"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="800dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_arrow_left"
                android:layout_weight="0.17">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70px" android:layout_marginLeft="60px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_birramorrety" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="50dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20px">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/txt_blahblah" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_width="35dp"></View>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_btl2" android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note: you should not use so many nested layouts. Try to use RelativeLayout insted.

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't get your question or it should be quite simple; add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the root LinearLayout, and add an `<ImageView/>` above the scrollview?

Comment: oh! Is it that simple? Let me give it a try.. Is there any way I can upload an image here so that you get a clear idea?